# Visual Studio: How to find all calls to function

Tags: visual-studio-2012

There are two calls to the function B:Bla below, but looking at the call hierarchy (Cntl-K Cntl-T) and then 'Calls to' for each of A:Bla and B:Bla yields that one call is going to A and one call is going to B.

I'm working on a very large code base and sometimes I want the all calls to a function and I don't want to click 'Calls to' for each function in the inheritance chain. So for the below example, I would like 'Calls to' to return both calls, regardless of whether I called it on A:Bla or B:Bla.

```
using System;

class A
{
    public virtual int Bla() {
        return 65;
    }
}

class B : A
{
    public override int Bla()
    {
        return 66;
    }

    int Helper()
    {
        return this.Bla();
    }

    static void Main()
    {
        A obj = new B();
        Console.WriteLine(obj.Bla());
        Console.Read();
    }
}
```

Comment: In "both" cases? I only see one call being made to `Bla`.

Comment: See this.Bla() and obj.Bla()

Comment: You're not calling `Helper()` aywhere.

Comment: The call isn't being executed, but it's still there...

Comment: There isn't any way that static code analysis tools can **reliably** figure out which virtual method is going to be called.  That's a *feature* of the virtual keyword, not a bug in the tooling.  Check out any book about OOP from your local library to get insight.

Comment: @HansPassant I know... I was asking for all possibilities. I.e. taking union of 'Call Hierachy''s 'Call to' on each ancestor and child.

Answer (score 13):

You can use the 'Find All References' function, highlight the method in question and press Ctrl + F12, or right click and pick Find All References.

This will then show the results in the Find Symbol Results window.

Please see this link for more details information. http://www.blackwasp.co.uk/VSFindAllReferences.aspx

Comment: Find All References will return more information than is desired. It returns all references... including override and parent definitions of function.

Comment: For me (C++ project in VS 2015) it returns also completely unrelated bogus identifiers based only on string equality, !even strings in comments, including framework files in include path. This function is completely useless.

Answer (score 5):

In Visual Studio 2015, try View | Call Hierarchy, or `Ctrl + Alt + K` on standard keyboard mapping. This brings up a tree with "call to " and "Calls from " subtrees.

Unfortunately, unlike Eclipse CDT, this call graph does not appear to be indexed.

Answer (score 2):

In case someone finds their way here looking for a way to do it with VS Code:

- Highlight a method and use `shift`+`F12`, or
- Right click on a method and choose `Find All References`

Answer (score 2):

Here are the basic shortcuts for function references :

- Find all references: Shift + Alt + F12
- Peek references: Shift + F12

*Using Windows version 1.31.1*